Can I apply for Schengen Visa from a country where I'm not resident but a citizen?
I'm Indian citizen residing in Ireland for work. I'm looking to apply for Schengen visa (business) from India where I'm a citizen but not a resident. Is it possible?
Any assistance would be appreciated please.

This depends on the policies of the destination country, so we need to know that. Some countries only accept applications at he consulate competent for your place of residence. Others may be more flexible, but usually still prefer applications in your country of residence as it makes checks easier, especially if there’s anything peculiar in your application.

Does this answer your question? Applying for Schengen visa in India while doing PhD in US

In general, you are supposed to apply from Ireland. That's the general rule, defined in article 6(1) of the Schengen visa code.
The same article also allows consulates to accept applications from people "legally present but not residing in its jurisdiction" but only if you have a justification for applying there instead of your normal residence. In practice, it means you will have to fight VFS to lodge the application and it's largely up to the consulate whether they will examine it. But it's not impossible.
The country of citizenship is not mentioned and doesn't play any special role. You could conceivably apply from any place in the world, if you can explain why you have to be there and could not practically go back to Ireland to apply but you do not have a right to apply from India because you are an Indian citizen.

You may be correct in theory, but in practice, is proof of residence really required if you have an Indian passport?  The bigger problem will be demonstrating ties to India if you don't actually live there.

@lambshaanxy Thought about that and for other purposes I would agree. I don't think providing proof of resident or establishing ties to India are the main problems either but for a visa application you have to detail your employment and income and deception can backfire badly. In practice, that means providing pay slips, bank statements, tax return, and a whole lot of other documents strongly suggesting you actually live in Ireland. Consulates in India probably even expect the letter Indian employers give to their employees when they approve leave.

My answer does indeed explain how it should work in theory but if anything, I would actually expect consulates to be more (not less) restrictive in practice than what the letter of the law suggests. Unless you are very wealthy and expect to get a visa just on the basis of owning businesses and properties, you will have to get into all that. And in the unlikely event that the OP's situation means they have a strong application without providing any evidence of employment in Ireland, merely omitting to mention it could easily appear deceptive.

So I would strongly advise the OP to tackle the question head on in their application rather than trying to imply they reside in India.

This answer is wrong and misleading

You could apply from your home country it’s clearly mentioned in the EU common sheet for Schengen if you say it’s not there you are definitely misleading and providing without any source of reliable reference

This is totally false : you do not have a right to apply from India because you are an Indian citizen. You do have the right to apply from India as you are an Indian citizen

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@SaranshSharma Have you read article 6 of the Schengen Visa Code? What's unclear about it? If you had asked politely, I could provide additional explanations, a quote, a link, or formal citation (it's regulation No 810/2009). But since I mentioned it in the first sentence of my answer, accusing me of not providing any source or reliable reference is a blatant lie and it does not seem you are commenting in good faith.

I think your answer is simply wrong which is what not OPs asking for

Just to add here : Citizenship is a legal status of personhood and membership in a sovereign state. Citizenship is permanent. Residency, on the other hand, is a permit that allows an individual to reside in a specific country with conditions that must be adhered to. Residency can be either temporary or permanent.

@SaranshSharma That's somewhat incorrect, there are many slightly different definition of residency but it's primarily the material fact or living and residing in a place. A residence permit allows non-citizen to take up residency but that's not the same thing. In any case, article 6 of regulation No 810/2009 the Schengen Visa Code only refers to residency. Have you read it?

Well in your opinion everything is incorrect except the Visa code article 6 anyhow I still think your answer is misleading you should try and research more. I think that’s not the concern here since OP will have to provide facts for proving where they actually live but OPs concern here if they can apply for visa from home country and the answer is always going to be yes regardless of residency since they are a citizen of that country it’s finally up to them where to choose to apply. I see you have made this discussion about just article 6

@SaranshSharma Regulation No 810/2009 is the controlling regulation, that's where the rules are defined and that's what consulates have to follow. Any other document you might find is just explaining what the regulation and in particular article 6 says. The only way my answer could be misleading is if I misinterpreted it because it does come down to what the regulation mean in any case.

Yes you can and maybe you cannot , as Indian citizen you are  welcome to apply for Schengen visa and as Indian citizen you don’t need to prove your residency in your home country, but embassy would want to know where did you live in last 6 months according the rule as Article 6 states in Schengen code
So you should contact the embassy and probably explain your circumstances and see if it works , personally I have heard of stories where it worked and where it didn’t. I have called the Estonian embassy also enquiring about this exact case they said they are willing to look at my complete case meaning the person asked me what’s my purpose and where did I live last 6 months and see if they can help, it’s totally up to the embassies
You should ask maybe your circumstances fits the bill !
Sorry for confusion
sources

As a general rule, you must apply for a Schengen visa at the Consulate with territorial competence for the country in which you legally reside.


WHO CAN APPLY FOR A SCHENGEN VISA IN INDIA?
Indian nationals and nationals of other countries legally residing in India can apply.

VFS Common Sheet Derived from EU Law

This is wrong. The text you are quoting is ambiguous, as it is not clear if 'legally residing in India' only apply to 'nationals of other countries' or also 'Indian nationals'. If you had also quoted the following sentence: 'Persons who do not reside in India may only apply ...', it would have been obvious that also Indian citizens are not necessarily able to apply for a Schengen visa from India unless they also reside there. The general rule for Schengen visas, with very few exceptions, is that the visa application must be made at the place of your residence.

The text I am quoting is from EU website and is used by VFS , you are twisting with words , there is no residency requirements for Indian citizens , I request not to downvote just because you don’t understand this

I am not twisting the words. You however are cherry-picking isolated statements without context. I even copied the sentence following the section you quoted, which clearly shows that you misinterpret the statement, which I also already pointed out is poorly written and ambiguous. Relaxed has already pointed you to the relevant regulation and you could have read there: 'An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.'

And my dear friend a citizen of a nation can legally reside in their home country or not ?

Can reside, yes, but does not have to. I do not reside in my home country. You are required to apply for a Schengen visa at your place of residence, not at a place where you are entitled to reside.

The words are not ambiguous actually if I say Indian National it just means Citizens of India can apply irregardless of the residency status of the Indian national, like I have EU residency but still I could come to India and apply any visa to any country they don’t ask me about my legal status my passport is the legal identifier which clearly mentions my address. I think Indian passport has address on it so it’s your residential address even though you are not staying there

Anyhow I could go and ask the embassy right now and confirm with them if I could apply for the visa if I am a resident outside India.

OP of the similar question you already answered incorrectly just a few days ago has already been in touch with the embassy and they told him that he can not apply for a visa unless he actually resides in India. You can of course contact the embassy as well if you don't believe that, but there is already an official confirmitation that you are wrong.

Not true this is spreading misinformation and jumping up ahead the other answer does not mention anything except VFS. I called the Estonian embassy so they said yes 6 months rule of residency is checked so you are all right but now I am confused because I applied for Schengen visa bypassing the six month rule. Anyhow I withdraw it seems like you are correct this 6 months rule is there even though you are the citizen.

@SaranshSharma I see where the confusion comes from. The thing is that the consulate is basically free to ignore the rule (in theory only if you provided a justification but it's really up to them) but it's not up to you. So you can always try and chances are the consulate will decline but the law does not say that they have to. As I wrote in my answer from the get go, it's not impossible but it's wrong to suggest that you have “a right” to see your application processed by a consulate in India in the OP's circumstances.

Yes it’s all about the circumstances true agreed
